# Haskell: parse error possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets

Tags: haskell

When I try to use the function below to implement a function like below the compiler return

> parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)

The function:

> demo 8 [1,2,3]    should return   [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2]

```
 demo :: Int -> [a] -> [a] 
    let n = 0 
    demo arg [] = [] 
    demo arg (x:xs) = 
         if arg <= length (x:xs) then
             take arg (x:xs) 
         else
             let (x:xs) = (x:xs) ++ (x:xs)!!n
             arg = arg - 1
             n = n + 1
             demo arg (x:xs)
```

How can I correct that?
Regards!

Comment: `possibly incorrect indentation`. The `let..in` block looks like it's incorrectly indented. Try to experiment with its indentation to get the code to compile.

Comment: `let arg = arg-1` and `let n=n+1` are recursive definition which define `arg` and `n` as infinite looping computations. You don't want that. You are trying to mutate variables in Haskell, which was designed so to make that impossible. That approach is too imperative to work in a FP language. Roughly, the only way to "change" a variable is to call a function with the new value, eg. `f 0 = 0 ; f n = f (n-1)` defines a recursion that "decreases" `n` until it reaches 0.

Answer (score 7):

You are mixing imperative and functional paradigms: `let n = 0`, `let (x:xs) = (x:xs) ++ (x:xs)!!n`, `arg = arg - 1`, `n = n + 1` are (in your code) imperative expressions. You expect the values of `n`, `(x:xs)` and `arg` to be modified, but functional programming does not work like that.

The function you are declaring is meant to be *pure*: that means that you can't expect values to be modified (what we call a "side effect"). The only thing you can do is to call a new function (or the same function) with new arguments that are computed "on the fly" from the original arguments.

Let's try to be concrete.

You can't do:

```
arg = arg - 1
demo arg (x:xs)
```

But you can do:

```
demo (arg - 1) (x:xs)
```

The latter is a call of `demo` with `arg - 1` as argument. The value of `arg` was never modified.

The main problem in your code is the `n` variable. It should be `0` at first call, and should be increased each time `arg < length (x:xs)` to add the next element from `(x:xs)` to the end of `(x:xs)` itself. Thus, the list will grow in a cyclic way until we can take the desired number of elements.

To reach that goal, you have to create an auxiliary function and to "move" the recursion into that auxiliary function:

````
demo :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
demo arg [] = [] 
demo arg (x:xs) = demo' arg 0 (x:xs) -- n = 0
    where 
        demo' :: Int -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
        demo' arg n l = if arg <= length l 
                        then take arg l 
                        else 
                            -- call demo' with new parameters:
                            -- (x:xs) = (x:xs) ++ [(x:xs)!!n]
                            -- arg = arg - 1
                            -- n = n + 1 
                            demo' (arg-1) (n+1) ((x:xs) ++ [(x:xs)!!n]) ```
````

Now, from the example you have given, `arg` is the constant number of elements in the list you want to create, so it should not be decreased. And you don't need the deconstruction of the list in `(x:xs)`. Finally, with a little cleanup, you have :

```
demo :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
demo arg [] = [] 
demo arg l = demo' arg 0 l
    where 
        demo' :: Int -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
        demo' arg n l = if arg <= length l 
                        then take arg l 
                        else demo' arg (n+1) (l ++ [l!!n])
```

There is a far better way to achieve this (`demo n=take n.cycle`), but I tried to stay close to your original implementation.

Comment: Thanks jferard! Your code is exactly what I mean.  And I thought the problem is caused by variable n, but I don't know how to fix that, thanks for answer my question.

Comment: @Sean You are welcome. You should accept either my answer or ephemient's one.

Answer (score 3):

You can't write `let n = 0` at the top level. Once you remove that, the `else let` portion of your code is not correctly indented either, as its use (outside of a `do` block) is always `let ... in ...`, and the contents of the `let` portion must be equally indented. Even if it were formatted, `let` is recursive, so `arg = arg - 1` means a value which is one less than itself, which doesn't compute.

Now, this function actually does two things: it cycles through all the elements of the list, and also limits it to a given length. Both of these are already available in the standard library.

```
demo n xs = take n (cycle xs)
```

If you wanted to write it yourself, a similar breakdown is also reasonable.

```
demo :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
-- Handle negative n, so we can assume it's positive below
demo n _ | n < 0 = []
-- Similarly, handle empty list, so we can assume it's non-empty below
demo _ [] = []
-- Given a positive n and non-empty list, start cycling list with limit n.
demo n list = demo' n list
  where
    -- Limit has been reached, stop.
    demo' 0 _ = []
    -- List is exhausted, cycle back to the start.
    demo' m [] = demo' m list
    -- Take the next element of the list and continue.
    demo' m (x:xs) = x : demo' (m-1) xs
```

Note that it was not necessary to use `length`, which is a good thing! `length` diverges on infinite lists, while this handles them gracefully.